# Unity C# Player Prefs Highscore not working

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Im having an error with PlayerPrefs in unity (C#)
on Android

It seems like it doesnt save it

Script 1

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Scores : MonoBehaviour
{
    public static int highscore;
    public static int points;

    public void Start()
    {

    }

    public void Update()
    {
            highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");
            PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", highscore);
            PlayerPrefs.Save();
    }
}
```

Script 2 (Part where it is used)

```
    void Update()
    {
        highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("Highscore");


        if (points > highscore)
        {
            highscore = points;
            highscoretext.text = "Highscore: " + highscore;
            highscoretext2.text = "Highscore: " + highscore;
        }
```

i just can figure it out when i get a highscore for example 12 and i die i go back to the mainscreen and then back to the game and the highscore is game same when restarting the app

Answer (score 0):

When you're setting the high score right now you are getting the current high score and storing it in the `highscore` variable. You then proceed to overwrite the high score with the `highscore` variable, effectively setting the high score to itself. What you actually want to do is check if the current score is more than the high score, and if it is you set the high score to the current score.

```
highscore = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("highscore");
if(score > highscore)
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetInt("highscore", score);
    PlayerPrefs.Save();
}
```

Another reason why your code doesn't work is that you spell `"highscore"` with a small h in script 1, but a big h in script 2.

Also, calling `PlayerPrefs.GetInt` every update is very inefficient. You should make them into functions that you only call when you need to get or set the high score.

Comment: Thanks for the help the saving the highscore works now but the display of the highscore is not working anymore

Comment: @Roanus Try getting rid of `if(score > highscore)` and `highscore = score;` in script 2. You don't need it there since you already checked that score was bigger than highscore in script 1.
Edit: Nevermind, I didn't see your second reply